# restricting input to certain numbers only in a textbox

Tags: asp.net, validation

I need to allow input in a textbox only for **certain** numbers (200, 300, 400, 600, 1000 or 1200), anything else shouldn't be accepted.
How can I do that using asp:RegularExpressionValidator?

Comment: If it's a very limited list - why textbox? Why not a dropdown?

Comment: Idd. For some reason didn't think about it. Thank you!
So concentrated on playing with validator, that more easy options just went out of my mind.